# Converting Joda 1.6.2 DateTime to 2.1 DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am stuck using a project that uses Joda 1.6.2. I would like to be able to take advantage of the 2.1 `DateTime`, which has a `withTimeAtStartOfDay()` method, so I could write code like so:

```
DateTime rightNow = new DateTime(System.currentTimeInMillis(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime startOfDay = rightnow.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Unfortunately this method was added at some point *after* 1.6.2. Again, I can't upgrade the JAR, so I ask: how do I achieve the same functionality with the [1.6.2 version](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/joda-time/joda-time/1.6.2/joda-time-1.6.2-javadoc.jar!/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) of Joda Time? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 2.1 source, withTimeAtStartOfDay() is defined as:

```
public DateTime withTimeAtStartOfDay() {
        return toLocalDate().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(getZone());
}
```

So, you can add this definition to your class, as [toDateTimeAtStartOfDay](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/joda-time/joda-time/1.6.2/joda-time-1.6.2-javadoc.jar!/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay%28%29) is present in 1.6.2. Hope that helped.